# Webdriver click element by coordinates twice

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, click

I have a page which allow to configure server part of some application. After providing some changes I need to click 'Submit' button. After clicking 'Submit' button the page is **reloaded** and message about changing configuration appear on the top of page.

I want to reproduce following bug: 
If click twice and fast 'Submit' button - two identical message about changing config appear instead of one.
I try following:
1. Only first click executed, and then I recieved 'JavaScript Error: "can't access dead object"'

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(button);
action.click().perform();
action.click().perform();
```

2.In this case nothing happen

```
Point p = button.getLocation();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String s = "(document.elementFromPoint(" + p.x + " - window.pageXOffset, " + p.y + " - window.pageYOffset)).click()";
js.executeScript(s);
js.executeScript(s);
```

3. The same as above, but without `window.pageXOffset` recieved `document.elementFromPoint(...) is null`

1. Also I was trying `action.moveToElement(button).doubleClick().build().perform()`but In this case only one message appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the element selected in Java, so no need to use coords in JS. Just pass the WebElement to your JS, and then you can avoid `.elementFromPoint(...)` being null:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", button);
```

Also, every time you execute a new JS from SE, there is some overhead time before the JS executes. You can get the second click faster, by doing both clicks in a single JS:

```
js.executeScript("var clicks = 0; while (clicks < 2) {arguments[0].click(); clicks++;}", button);
```